# Vertices counter/clockwise

Tags: opengl, vertices

I am reading several books about OpenGL and in two of them they always define the vertices counter clockwise. From what I read this is very crucial because it determines where the front and back is.

But I am also reading the tutorial on http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ And he defines them clockwise.

```
const float vertexPositions[] = {
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

Shouldn't I always use the counter clockwise notation, because that is the default in opengl?

Also why is the type a `float`? Shouldn't it be a `GLfloat`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Shouldn't I always use the counter clockwise notation, because that is
>   the default in opengl?

That is your choice. You can use CCW or CW notation. You can always override this behaviour with `glFrontFace()`. There is no difference for the hardware, which way to work, but, I guess, chosing CW might cause some unexpected troubles when trying to use third-party library which prefers CCW or something like that.

> Also why is the type a float? Shouldn't it be a GLfloat?

It should be `GLfloat`. On the other hand, on most platforms `float` and `GLfloat` are exactly the same and one can't find any difference. Using `GLfloat` is better practice from portability point of view. Another consideration: it emphasizes that the variable is used for graphics rendering, so it's a good thing to do.